# windows forms input continuously showing

Tags: c#, windows

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to continuously show the input and then output of the numbers for this.

**What do you do to store the numbers somewhere and then show them?** I've gone in so many circles that I have confused myself to oblivion.
I know what needs to be done but not how or exactly where to do it?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    char c;
    double num1;
    double num2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 0;
    }
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 1;
    }
    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 2;
    }
    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 3;
    }
    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 4;
    }
    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 5;
    }
    private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 6;
    }
    private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 7;
    }
    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 8;
    }
    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 9;
    }
    private void btnDecimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtBox.Text.Contains('.'))
            txtBox.Text += '.';
    }
    private void btnAddition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '+';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void btnSubtraction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '-';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void btnMultiplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '*';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void btnDivision_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '/';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Clear();
    }
    private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        num2 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        double result;
        switch (c)
        {
            case '+':
                result = num1 + num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                break;
            case '-':
                result = num1 - num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                break;
            case '/':
                if (num2 != 0)
                {
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtBox.Text = "You can't divide by zero... sign up for Math 100 please =)";
                }
                break;
            case '*':
                result = num1 * num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by store the numbers somewhere and show them, or continuously show them.  Are they not displaying properly in txtBox.text?

Comment: They display in sequence, such as if i click 9 it shows 9. If I click 9 + 2 its just a 9, then a 2 and if I click 9 + 2 = then it gives 11. I want it to always display what I click. Maybe I did not title this correctly and I apologize. It was hard to communicate this.

Comment: What is your question? All I can see bunch of event handlers and something that looks like code for calculator.

Comment: @Mayank the question is how to display continuously the input values. I want the textBox.Text to show everything I click instead in a continuous action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll let you wire this up, but here is what I threw together.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string op;
    private string num1;
    private string num2;

    private void handleNumberButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var num = Convert.ToInt16(((Button)sender).Tag);
        if (op == null)
            num1 += num;
        else
            num2 += num;
        PrintEquation(num1, op, num2);
    }

    private void PrintEquation(string first, string oper = null, string second = null, string equals = null, string result = null)
    {
        txtBox.Text = first + oper + second + equals + result;
    }

    private void handleOperatorButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        op = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();
        PrintEquation(num1, op);
    }

    private void btnDecimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (op == null && !num1.Contains(".")) num1 += ".";
        if (op != null && !num2.Contains(".")) num2 += ".";
        this.PrintEquation(num1, op, num2);
    }
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Clear();
        op = null;
        num1 = null;
        num2 = null;
    }
    private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double result = 0;
        var first = Convert.ToDouble(num1);
        var second = Convert.ToDouble(num2);
        switch (op)
        {
            case "+":
                result = first + second;
                break;
            case "-":
                result = first - second;
                break;
            case "/":
                if (second != 0)
                {
                    result = first / second;
                }
                else
                {
                    errorLbl.Text = "You can't divide by zero... sign up for Math 100 please =)";
                }
                break;
            case "*":
                result = first * second;
                break;
        }
        this.PrintEquation(num1, op, num2, "=", result.ToString());
    }
}
```

To give you a clue on how things go together, this is what the button should look like in the .designer.cs file:

```
        this.btn0.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 60);
        this.btn0.Name = "btn0";
        this.btn0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.btn0.TabIndex = 1;
        this.btn0.Tag = "0";
        this.btn0.Text = "btn0";
        this.btn0.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btn0.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.handleNumberButtonClick);
```

Notice the .Tag value and the eventhandler.

The Operators should look like this(this is add, notice the tag and the Click Event handler):

```
        this.addButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(178, 60);
        this.addButton.Name = "addButton";
        this.addButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.addButton.TabIndex = 11;
        this.addButton.Tag = "+";
        this.addButton.Text = "add";
        this.addButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.addButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.handleOperatorButtonClick);
```

And the decimal, like this:

```
        this.button4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(178, 176);
        this.button4.Name = "button4";
        this.button4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button4.TabIndex = 15;
        this.button4.Tag = ".";
        this.button4.Text = "decimal";
        this.button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnDecimal_Click);
```

Oh, and throw this in your clear button definition

```
        this.button5.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClear_Click);
```

Special thanks to [@Mark Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479512/mark-hall) and [@Martin James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758133/martin-james) for their insights

Comment: This might sound dumb, but I am new to programming. Will you please explain why I should do this so I may understand it entirely? Please.

Comment: There is also an issue with his Parse Statements that he is going to have to address since once he gets his `+/-*=` in his textbox it will no longer parse to a double

Comment: Good point @MarkHall.  Perhaps instead of the buttons pushing to `txtBox.Text` they should populate num1 and num2

Comment: @paqogomez He is going need to do something like that, or write a routine to parse the TextBox.Text Value.

Comment: Like a parse at the end of the switch?

Comment: @Azzamean I wasn't talking about double.Parse statement, I was talking about iterating through your Text and parsing out the information, performing your math then displaying it.

Comment: Hint - the 0-9 buttons can all use the same btn_Click handler.  Load the Tag property of each buton with 0..9 and then get the property back from the sender object: txtBox.Text +=(sender as Button).Tag

Comment: So I need to parse the character? Or wouldn't it be the whole string that goes into the case for whatever type of math I would be doing. If so, I do not know how you parse a string...

Comment: Take a look at my edit, it should all be there.  just needs wiring up.

Comment: I started windows forms 4 days ago, so I really dont know a lot about this. I figured a calculator would be easy and while it isnt as easy as I thought I am learning a lot! Thanks to everyone!!